# React Router *Not Found* rendered first before main routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i am working on a huge project and i have an authorization system where *Logged in* users can access certain routes while the **Not Found** component, served on *Logged Out* Users. The problem is, when a user is marked as *logged in* and has a valid token and then proceed into a page (*e.g /account*), the component **Not Found** is rendered first and a second later the component **account** is rendered correctly.

I have an async *componentDidMount* where i validate my token and if it's valid, i set the state of *isLogged: true*. Also on each route in my switch i am checking the the state of *isLogged* and only then i send the corresponding component.

**My async componentDidMount**

```
{/* Username is from localstorage */}

async componentDidMount() {
  if ((USERNAME != "") && (USERNAME != null)) {
    const logged = await checkTheToken({'Username': USERNAME}).then((result) => {
      if(result.status == 202) {
         this.setState({isLogged: true});
         this.setState({checking: false});
      };
    });
  }
}
```

**This is the Router** (* supposing we are trying to access */user* page. Notice i use react-router, react-router-dom ^4.1.1* )

```
   if (this.state.checking) {
        return null;
   } else {
   return ( 
     <Router>
        <Switch>
            {/* This is Not Rendered First and Not Found rendered before FALSLY */}

            {this.state.isLogged && <Route exact path="/user" component={() => (<User isLogged={this.state.isLogged} username={USERNAME} />)} />}

            {/* This is Rendered First and Not Found is not rendering at all CORRECTLY */}

            <Route exact path="/test" component={() => (<Test isLogged={this.state.isLogged} />)} />

            <Route component={() => (<NotFound isLogged={this.state.isLogged} />)} />
        </Switch>
     </Router>
   );
```

I think the problem is in the **{this.state.isLogged && ...}** because if we try to access */test* the component is rendered correctly without *Not Found* rendering first.

Also, I tested all the lifecycle methods

Comment: Have you tried doing the auth check  in `componentWillMount`, your component has already rendered before it gets to `componentDidMount`.

Comment: I tested all the lifecycle methods

Comment: You probably need to add a state field like `checking` that defaults to `true`. And when you have got a response either success or error set `checking` to `false`. In your render `if(this.state.checking) return null;`.

Comment: i've updated my question based on your comment. Home is not rendered at all now

Comment: Which is `Home`? You need to move the `this.state({checking: ..` outside the `if(result.status...)` and you also need to put it where you catch if the request has errors. as `checking` needs to be set to `false` regardless of the response from your auth check. If you are not getting any errors and it definitely setting state then the code looks fine. I don't think you need to have the `async`/`await` on your `componentDidMount` function either since we are using state to manage the asynchronous nature of your auth check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right and the issue comes from `{this.state.isLogged && ...}`

Lets take it step by step.

First `this.state.isLogged` is falsy. It does mean that `<User isLogged={this.state.isLogged} username={USERNAME} />` is not currently in the ReactRouter configuration.

We can guess that ReactRouter will match the default component (`<Route component={() => (<NotFound isLogged={this.state.isLogged} />)} />`) since `/user` is not in its configuration.

The actual behavior is then correct.

The fastest way to archieve your goal would be to move the token check into your child component with something like this :

```
async componentDidMount() {
  if ((USERNAME != "") && (USERNAME != null)) {
    const logged = await checkTheToken({'Username': USERNAME}).then((result) => {
      if(result.status !== 202) {
        history.push('/not-found')
      } else {
        this.setState({isLogged: true});
        this.setState({checking: false});
      };
    });
  }
}
```

Rendering function would like this :

```
render () {
 if(!this.state.isLogged) return <span />
 return <div>...</div>
}
```

The main problem with this aproach is that it would require all your authenticated components to implement this.

You'll also need to factorize the code into a service to avoid multiple calls.

A 2nd approach would be to fatorize this into a proxy component that do the check like this :

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route component={Authenticated}>
           <Route exact path="/user" component={() => (<User isLogged={this.state.isLogged} username={USERNAME} />)} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/test" component={() => (<Test isLogged={this.state.isLogged} />)} />
        <Route component={() => (<NotFound isLogged={this.state.isLogged} />)} />
    </Switch>
 </Router>
```

This component will now be the one who carry the token check.

Rendering function would look like this :

```
render () {
 if(!this.state.isLogged) return <span />
 return {this.props.children}
}
```

Main problem here is that you can't easily share between your component the "this.state.isLogged"

If you want to share and update mutiple component using some global state, i highly suggest you to give a look at [Redux](http://redux.js.org/).

Since redux can have a hard learning curve, if you only need to share this single value, you could try some things using the observable pattern. (Example : [observable service](https://jsfiddle.net/qcdmuzac/1/), [observable service + connector](https://jsfiddle.net/qcdmuzac/2/) )

All my code example are not tested and are here to guide you in the right direction. In my opinion there is a lot of way to archieve what you want, sadly i can only tell you why it currently do not work and i hope i gave you enough clues to find a solution adapted to your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I moved the checkToken on each corresponding component. As a result, each component on ComponentDidMount has to check for isLogged user. I dont think if this is optimized (possibly not) but it works. I prefer to avoid multiple calls to db when i load my component and i prefer to pass the value from one component to another through props but i think is the only way. 

Regarding the 2nd approach, i have react router v4 and i cannot add nested Routes on my Router. I tried to downgrade the Router but i receive multiple errors let me know if you want to update the question

Comment: As you said i have to factorize the code into a service. I'll check it.

Comment: And a 2nd example on how to make a connector for your service https://jsfiddle.net/qcdmuzac/2/